# Can't start PostgreSQL on Manjaro 21.2.5

Tags: postgresql, psql, manjaro

I cannot start PostgreSQL 13.6 on Manjaro 21.2.5 running inside VirtualBox.
How to get PostgreSQL to work with Manjaro?
I downloaded PostgreSQL using the Manjaro package manager.
Thank you!

```
    ~  psql                                                             ✔ 
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
    ~  postgres                                                       2 ✘ 
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
    ~                                                                 2 ✘ 
    ~  sudo systemctl status postgresql                             INT ✘ 
[sudo] password for jon: 
○ postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vend>
     Active: inactive (dead)
    ~  sudo systemctl start postgresql                        3 ✘  25s  
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql.service" for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized the database?

```sh
initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data/'
```

You might also need to start the service before running `psql` through `systemctl` if you haven't already:

```sh
sudo systemctl enable --now postgresql.service
```